# Python HttpConnection request encoding error

Tags: python

I'm trying to use a python script to upload a zip file to a site. The site provided an API exactly for that purpose. But, when I tried to use it, an encoding error showed up when joining all the strings to send in the httplib connect request. I've traced the string in question to be the `filedata` (my zip file).

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Application Junk/ProjectManager/Main.py", line 146, in OnUpload CurseUploader.upload_file('77353ba57bdeb5346d1b3830ed36171279763e35', 'wow', slug, version, VersionID, 'r', logText or '', 'creole', '', 'plain', zipPath)
File "/Library/Application Junk/ProjectManager/CurseUploader.py", line 83, in upload_file
content_type, body = encode_multipart_formdata(params, [('file', filepath)])
File "/Library/Application Junk/ProjectManager/CurseUploader.py", line 153, in encode_multipart_formdata
body = '\r\n'.join(L)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xcb in position 10: ordinal not in range(128)
```

---

**EDIT**: As requested, the full code.

**EDIT2**: Tried, as suggested, to encode all the not-ascii strings to ascii. It throws the same bug, but now on `L[i] = value.encode("ascii")`.

```
from httplib import HTTPConnection
from os.path import basename, exists
from mimetools import choose_boundary

try:
    import simplejson as json
except ImportError:
    import json

def get_game_versions(game):
    """
    Return the JSON response as given from /game-versions.json from curseforge.com of the given game

`game`
    The shortened version of the game, e.g. "wow", "war", or "rom"
"""
conn = HTTPConnection('%(game)s.curseforge.com' % { 'game': game })
conn.request("GET", '/game-versions.json')
response = conn.getresponse()
assert response.status == 200, "%(status)d %(reason)s from /game-versions.json" % { 'status': response.status, 'reason': response.reason }

assert response.content_type == 'application/json'
data = json.loads(response.read())

return data

def upload_file(api_key, game, project_slug, name, game_version_ids, file_type, change_log, change_markup_type, known_caveats, caveats_markup_type, filepath):
"""
Upload a file to CurseForge.com on your project

`api_key`
    The api-key from http://www.curseforge.com/home/api-key/

`game`
    The shortened version of the game, e.g. "wow", "war", or "rom"

`project_slug`
    The slug of your project, e.g. "my-project"

`name`
    The name of the file you're uploading, this should be the version's name, do not include your project's name.

`game_version_ids`
    A set of game version ids.

`file_type`
    Specify 'a' for Alpha, 'b' for Beta, and 'r' for Release.

`change_log`
    The change log of the file. Up to 50k characters is acceptable.

`change_markup_type`
    Markup type for your change log. creole or plain is recommended.

`known_caveats`
    The known caveats of the file. Up to 50k characters is acceptable.

`caveats_markup_type`
    Markup type for your known caveats. creole or plain is recommended.

`filepath`
    The path to the file to upload.
"""

assert len(api_key) == 40
assert 1 <= len(game_version_ids) <= 3
assert file_type in ('r', 'b', 'a')
assert exists(filepath)

params = []

params.append(('name', name))

for game_version_id in game_version_ids:
    params.append(('game_version', game_version_id))

params.append(('file_type', file_type))
params.append(('change_log', change_log))
params.append(('change_markup_type', change_markup_type))
params.append(('known_caveats', known_caveats))
params.append(('caveats_markup_type', caveats_markup_type))

content_type, body = encode_multipart_formdata(params, [('file', filepath)])
print('Got here?')


headers = {
    "User-Agent": "CurseForge Uploader Script/1.0",
    "Content-type": content_type,
    "X-API-Key": api_key}

conn = HTTPConnection('%(game)s.curseforge.com' % { 'game': game })
conn.request("POST", '/projects/%(slug)s/upload-file.json' % {'slug': project_slug}, body, headers)
response = conn.getresponse()
if response.status == 201:
    print "Successfully uploaded %(name)s" % { 'name': name }
elif response.status == 422:
    assert response.content_type == 'application/json'
    errors = json.loads(response.read())
    print "Form error with uploading %(name)s:" % { 'name': name }
    for k, items in errors.iteritems():
        for item in items:
            print "    %(k)s: %(item)s" % { 'k': k, 'name': name }
else:
    print "Error with uploading %(name)s: %(status)d %(reason)s" % { 'name': name, 'status': response.status, 'reason': response.reason }

def is_ascii(s):
return all(ord(c) < 128 for c in s)

def encode_multipart_formdata(fields, files):
"""
Encode data in multipart/form-data format.

`fields`
    A sequence of (name, value) elements for regular form fields.

`files`
    A sequence of (name, filename) elements for data to be uploaded as files
Return (content_type, body) ready for httplib.HTTP instance
"""
boundary = choose_boundary()
L = []

for key, value in fields:
    if value is None:
        value = ''
    elif value is False:
        continue

    L.append('--%(boundary)s' % {'boundary': boundary})
    L.append('Content-Disposition: form-data; name="%(name)s"' % {'name': key})
    L.append('')
    L.append(value)

for key, filename in files:
    f = file(filename, 'rb')
    filedata = f.read()
    f.close()
    L.append('--%(boundary)s' % {'boundary': boundary})
    L.append('Content-Disposition: form-data; name="%(name)s"; filename="%(filename)s"' % { 'name': key, 'filename': basename(filename) })
    L.append('Content-Type: application/zip')
    L.append('')
    L.append(filedata)

L.append('--%(boundary)s--' % {'boundary': boundary})
L.append('')

for i in range(len(L)):
    value = L[i]
    if not is_ascii(value):
        L[i] = value.encode("ascii")

body = '\r\n'.join(L)
content_type = 'multipart/form-data; boundary=%(boundary)s' % { 'boundary': boundary }
return content_type, body
```

How can I workaround it?

---

**EDIT3**: As requested, the full result of printing the vars

```
fields: [('name', u'2.0.3'), ('game_version', u'1'), ('game_version', u'4'), ('game_version', u'9'), ('file_type', 'r'), ('change_log', u'====== 2.0.3\n* Jaliborc: Fixed a bug causing wrong items to be shown for leather, mail and plate slots\n* Jaliborc: Items are now organized by level as well\n\n====== 2.0.2\n* Jaliborc: Completly rewritten the categories dropdown to fix a bug\n\n====== 2.0.1\n* Jaliborc: Updated for patch 4.2\n* Jaliborc: Included all Firelands items\n\n===== 2.0.0\n* Jaliborc: Now works with 4.1\n* Jaliborc: Completely redesigned and improved\n* Jaliborc: Includes **all** items in-game right from the start\n* Jaliborc: Searches trough thousands of items in a blaze\n* Jaliborc: Mostly //Load on Demand//\n* Jaliborc: Only works on English clients. Versions for other clients should be released in a close future.\n\n====== 1.8.7\n* Added linkerator support for multiple chat frames\n\n====== 1.8.6\n* Fixed a bug when linking an item from the chat frame. \n\n====== 1.8.5\n* Added compatibility with WoW 3.3.5\n\n====== 1.8.3\n* Bumped TOC for 3.3\n\n====== 1.8.2\n* Bumped TOC for 3.2\n\n====== 1.8.1\n* TOC Bump + Potential WIM bugfix\n\n===== 1.8.0\n* Added "Heirloom" option to quality selector\n* Fixed a bug causing the DB to be reloaded on item scroll\n* Cleaned up the code a bit.  Still need to work on the GUI/localization\n* Altered slash commands.  See addon description for details.\n\n====== 1.7.2\n* Bumped the max item ID to check from 40k to 60k.  Glyphs, etc, should now appear.\n\n====== 1.7.1\n* Fixed a crash issue when linking tradeskills\n\n===== 1.7.0\n* Made Wrath compatible\n* Seems to be causing a lot more CPU usage now, will investigate later.'), ('change_markup_type', 'creole'), ('known_caveats', ''), ('caveats_markup_type', 'plain')]

files: [('file', u'/Users/Jaliborc/Desktop/Ludwig 2.0.3.zip')]
```

It appears to contain some unicode strings. Should I encode them all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is highly likely that ISO-8859-1 is not the solution to your first problem. You need to be aware that `any_random_gibberish.decode('ISO-8859-1')` simply cannot fail.

Secondly, I'm not sure why an encoding would be needed when uploading a file -- surely the object of the exercise is to reproduce the file exactly on the server; decoding a zip file into `unicode` objects seems very strange.

It would be a very good idea if you were to publish the error that you got ("an encoding error showed up when reading the file") and the full traceback, then somebody can help you. Also needed: URL for the API that you mentioned.

**Update** You say that you got an "ascii error" in the line `body = '\r\n'.join(L)`. A reasonable guess, based on your limited information, is that you have this problem:

```
>>> "".join([u"foo", "\xff"])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

`u"foo" + "\xff"` produces the same result.

What is happening is that you have a mixture of `unicode` and `str` objects. Concatenating them requires converting the `str` object to `unicode`, and this is attempted using the default encoding, normally `ascii`, which will fail when the `str` object is not ASCII.

In this case the problem is not with the `str` objects, but with the `unicode` objects: you just can't send unencoded `unicode` objects down the wire.

I suggest that you replace this code:

```
for key, filename in files:
    f = file(filename, 'r')
    filedata = f.read().decode("ISO-8859-1")
```

with this:

```
for key, filename in files:
    f = file(filename, 'rb') # Specify binary mode in case this gets run on Windows
    filedata = f.read() # don't decode it
```

and immediately after entering that function, print its args so that you can see exactly which are `unicode`:

```
print "fields:", repr(fields)
print "files:", repr(files)
```

It is quite likely that the `unicode` objects can all be safely coerced to `ascii` by doing (explicitly) `unicode_object.encode("ascii")`.

**Update 2**: It is worth investigating how **some** of your values are `unicode`, and some are `str`. It appears that all the `unicode` can be safely encoded as `ascii`:

```
new = [(k, v.encode('ascii') if isinstance(v, unicode) else v) for k, v in original]
```

Comment: Ok, I added the full code an an explanation of the error previous to using `.decode('ISO-8859-1')`. And thank you for the quick answer!

Comment: @Jaliborc: You haven't shown (1) the actual error message that you got (2) the full traceback from the error (3) a URL for the API that you mentioned. "an ascii error showed up when calling '\r\n'.join(L)" is NOT an explanation, and an explanation is not expected -- if you could explain the error, you wouldn't need to be asking a question. Just use copy/paste to show the error message and traceback.

Comment: Ok I've included the full traceback of the error in the question. I've also tried your suggestion, but didn't work either. The API consists basically of the json request for getting the game version (first function) and the one for uploading the file with the given variables (as described in `upload_file`). It does not really matter: it's an encoding problem.

Comment: @Jaliborc: and what was the output of the print statements that showed the contents of the args?

Comment: Ok, you're right, it's full of unicode strings. Should I encode them all?

Comment: @Jaliborc: Yes you should encode them all. They appear to be all capable of being encoded into `ascii`. However I suggested that earlier, but you replied "I've also tried your suggestion, but didn't work either" -- please explain. Did you try to encode the `str` objects as well? See my updated answer.

Comment: Well, actually, between my post and yours, I figured it out:I simply had to call str(value) on any string appending to the L array. I thought I already had tried that, but I guess I did something wrong the last time. The `print fields` has really helped me to get there. Thank you!